# Build a libraries for OpenCV-3.1.0 with cuda_7.5.18_win10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I work with Windows 10 Pro x64 and I try to build libraries for OpenCV-3.1.0 with CUDA x64 (cuda_7.5.18_win10). I use IDE VS2013 x64 mode (I tried VS2010 too, but I can not try the x86 mode because the CUDA is x64). Unfortunately I got a lot error messages:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencl_kernels_core.hpp'
error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'opencl_kernels_core.cpp'
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencl_kernels_imgproc.hpp'
error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'opencl_kernels_imgproc.cpp'
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencl_kernels_video.hpp'
error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'opencl_kernels_video.cpp'
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencl_kernels_photo.hpp'
error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'opencl_kernels_photo.cpp'
... etc ...
```

Has somebody an answer?.. Thank you.